# Spark AFTSurvivalRegression parameters

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, regression

I have tried sample AFTSurvivalRegression  from Spark for Survival analysis.
It is so simple. For understanding label parameter i played some. In web I found it's usage in 2 ways. 
1)As a number of observations.
think label as patient count
      features = body temperature
label,censor,features
2,1,38
1,0,28
2 people with 38 degrees survived
1 people with 28 degrees did not survive

2)Another metric related like dose of medicine
this label as doseof medicine
label,censor,features
2,1,38
1,0,28
2 dose medicine survived 38 degree
2 dose medicine did not survive 28 degree

Maybe I am wrong on both them. Could not find an interpretation of parameters.
Checked R survreg function but confused more.
Does anyone know real meaning of label parameter?

```
val training = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
(1.218, 1.0, Vectors.dense(1.560, -0.605)),
(2.949, 0.0, Vectors.dense(0.346, 2.158)),
(3.627, 0.0, Vectors.dense(1.380, 0.231)),
(0.273, 1.0, Vectors.dense(0.520, 1.151)),
(4.199, 0.0, Vectors.dense(0.795, -0.226))
)).toDF("label", "censor", "features")
val quantileProbabilities = Array(0.3, 0.6)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The concept of `label` within the AFTSurvivalRegression model is in reference to supervised learning within Machine Learning (ML).  That is, the `label` is known value / category within your dataset.   For example, when attempting to predict median housing prices based on city population using linear regression (e.g. [Population vs. Price Linear Regression (Spark 2.0)](http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/438089/notebooks/Pop.%20vs.%20Price%20LR%202.0.html?t=1477388079493)), the `feature` is the city population (the vector that contains the information which we will use to predict the price) while the `label` is the value you are trying to predict.

In the example above (for reference, the full example can be found at [Spark Classification and Regression > Survival Regression](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#survival-regression)), the generated `labels` (e.g. 1.218, 2.949, ...) are the values to be predicted by the `features` (e.g. Vectors.dense(1.560, -0.605), Vectors.dense(0.346, 2.158), ...).

Saying this, a potentially easier way to showcase this is to use a specific survival analysis example.  In this case, we can use the ovarian cancer survival data that is shipped with the R package *survival*.   For example, if you were to run the `SparkR` code-snippet below:

```
# Create SparkR DataFrame from the ovarian cancer survival data
df <- createDataFrame(ovarian)
model <- spark.survreg(df, Surv(futime, fustat) ~ ecog_ps + rx)
fitted <- predict(model, df)
display(fitted)
```

The result would be:
[image]

Note that the `label` is the same as the `futime` - the survival or censoring time that we're ultimately trying to predict.  Note, the `prediction` column contains the results by predict function on survreg object in R, at the original scale of the data within the context of the Weibull distribution.  Below is a visualization of the four survival curves generated based on this dataset.

[image: Survival Curves from the Ovarian Cancer Data from R *survival* package]

To see the full notebooks in action, please refer to the links below:

- [Survival Analysis with SparkR (Updated to include
  AFTSurvivalRegression)](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/dennyglee/databricks/blob/e2de5a561adaef69b11b01ac5aa4d63a24ffc298/notebooks/Users/denny%40databricks.com/demo/health/Survival%20Analysis%20with%20SparkR.html)
- [Survival Analysis with SparkR (Original)](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/index.html#08%20Language%20References/00%20SparkR/4%20Survival%20Analysis%20Using%20AFT.html)

Comment: Dear Denny Lee , Thanks for your answer. What I am asking is what is business meaning. Futime is parameter to surv, so it is follow up time. Can we say (59,1)we followed up for 59 months(or whatever) and event occurred(dead).

Comment: so for prediction if event occured(fustat = 1) what is 1141? Is it time to fail?

Comment: The `prediction` column contains the results by predict function on survreg object in R, at the original scale of the data within the context of the Weibull distribution.  Will update my response to clarify this.

Comment: "Note that the label is the same as the futime - the survival or censoring time that we're ultimately trying to predict." Thank you! this note should be highlighted :-)